# Flush and ob_flush not working in fastcgi php

Tags: php, apache, fastcgi

is not working in php fastcgi

I have tried everything like disabled gzip and zip compression, disables output buffer but still not working

```
ob_start();
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
  echo $i."\n";
  ob_flush();
  flush();
  sleep(1);
}
```

Comment: If you add the code which is causing an issue, we may be able to see what the problem is.

Comment: I have added the code, it's working in my xamp Apache server but not my fastcgi php Apache server which is dedicated